# VaultSharp - How to generate a secret-id?

Tags: vaultsharp

I'm currently using the latest version of VaultSharp in a project.

Can you tell me if it's possible to generate a secret-id using the library please?

Something along the lines of: **vault write -force auth/apppole/role/myapp/secret-id**

Thank you in advance

Darren

Answer (score 0):

This capability will be available in the next Nuget publish of VaultSharp. I just added this feature last and it is checked in. It'll be available when I publish the next version in a week or so.

The feature is here: https://github.com/rajanadar/VaultSharp/blob/master/src/VaultSharp/V1/AuthMethods/AppRole/AppRoleAuthMethodProvider.cs#L67

```
Task<Secret<SecretIdInfo>> PullNewSecretIdAsync(string roleName, 
      PullSecretIdRequestOptions secretIdRequestOptions = null, 
      string mountPoint = AuthMethodDefaultPaths.AppRole);
```